# Expo Notifications addNotificationResponseReceivedListener not triggered when app starts from a terminated state

Tags: expo

I'm currently facing an issue with the Expo Notifications API. While my code works fine when the app is in the foreground or background, I can't get the addNotificationResponseReceivedListener to trigger when the app is launched from a terminated state by tapping on a notification.

```
useEffect(() => {
  init();

  const subscription = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
    (response) => {
      let payload = response.notification.request.content.data;

      if (payload)
        setPushPayload({
          idx: payload.idx,
          url: payload.url,
        });
    }
  );
  return () => Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(subscription);
}, []);
```

I'm testing on the Expo Go app, and the listener works perfectly when the app is in the foreground. However, when the app is terminated and I tap on a notification to launch the app, the listener doesn't seem to trigger.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can point out what might be missing or incorrect in my implementation? Any guidance would be appreciated!